# How do I translate this pattern of sentence into a quantified statement using logical operators?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

How do I translate this pattern of sentence into a quantified statement using logical operators?  (It's basically introducing a new symbol, "b" in this case, in a proof.)

***So a = xb where b is the integer yc.***

Do I go

$∃b ∈ Z, (b = yc ∧ a = xb)$

or

$(∃b ∈ Z ∧ b = yc), a = xb$

or

$∃b = yc ∈ Z, a = xb$

or neither?

What if defining "b" takes even more statements?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking which is the clearest to an audience? In that case I'd personally go with $$
\exists b \in \mathbb{Z},(b=y c \wedge a=x b)
$$
because it's a simple existence statement with the conditions. The second and third are a little more sloppy, for instance the third you may as well say $yc \in \mathbb{Z}$ and define $b = yc$.

I hope I understood and answered your question properly!

Comment: Thank you.  I'm more concerned about translating it correctly, but clarity is a bonus.